# Set the session value in jquery and get that value in Controller?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, session

Is it possible to set the session value in jquery and get that value in controller post method without using any ajax call. I am trying to set one list value to session in jquery

```
$.session.set('SelectedIdList', selectedIds);
```

now a want to get these value in Controller post method

```
public ActionResult SaveTransactions(BusinessViewModel model, string Submit)
{

  model.SelectedIdsList = (string[])Session["SelectedIdList"];
```

}

Comment: it is not possible, you can set by sending an ajax cal to a controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the session from my code I have taken one hidden field and looping that and storing the value with ',' which I am getting that in controller

```
      $("#hdnSelectedIdList").val("");
      for (var iCount = 0; iCount < SelectedIdList.length; iCount++) {
            $("#hdnSelectedIdList").val($("#hdnSelectedIdList").val() + ',' + SelectedIdList[iCount]);
        }

@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.hdnSelectedIdList)
```

and in controller

```
 model.SelectedIdsList = model.hdnSelectedIdList[0].Split(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot set in jquery as Session is a server side thing.

you have to send an ajax call if it is really needed like this:

```
$.ajax({

                url: '@Url.Action("SetSession","Controller")',
                data {session:1},
                success: function (response) {

                },
                error: function () {

                    alert("Error occured!");

                }

            });
```

in Action:

```
[HttpGet]
public Action Result SetSession(string session)
{
Session["key"] = session;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set and retrieve like this, since both the data are maintained in a different place. One is in browser and another one is in server.

[From **$.session** Plugin Author](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin)

Provides a simple interface into window.sessionStorage while providing limited support for cross protocol requests.

**ASP.Net Session**

This is basically maintained in the server side.